USB-C module configuration pins in parallel connection
I have received a lot of help from several members of this site. After trying to wire two charging ports on the same device and investigating the diode OR-ing configurations and the power mux configuration, members pointed out my mistake: the voltage drop of the diodes will not work. So, they recommended a parallel connection to me.
I am reassured that it is not an OTG port as many thought, but rather a charging-only connector (you can see the direct current symbol (DCIN) in the photo). However, I still have some concerns.
My question is, where do I make the CC connection in these modules? Another concern is that they recommended connecting both connectors (micro USB and USB-C) in parallel. Wouldn't that mean that I would have 5V in one of the receptacles without negotiation? Should I connect the two receptacles in parallel, or would this generate conflicts between the micro USB BC protocol and the pull-down resistors, even if it is only a charging port?



You've been already explained that to have your tablet charging in enhanced mode from Type-C port, you need to make a circuit to understand voltage levels on CC pins, and convert this information into charging signature that your tablet understands. This is the only way.

Did you determine what kind of charger signature is required for your tablet to charge at elevated level?

I believe most of your questions are repeats of your earlier questions that have been explained and answered already. I believe the answers have not changed since. You need to figure out if the 5th mystery pad is CC or not, we can't see that from the pictures.

@Ale..chenski Yes! It appears to be a DCP BC 1.2 with the data lines shorted by a 200Ω resistor. I am open to any suggestions you might have. Thanks for responding.

@Ale..chenski The question I have is that according to the information described on the laptop case it has an input voltage of 2.5 amp, I seem to remember that BC 1.2 accepts 1.5amp. Am I making an error or could it be an implementation?
